# Columns within columns

Tags: formatting, columns

I'm making a formula sheet for an exam. I want to have two columns and in the left column for example I want to add a box of text to the right of the formula for clarification. Here is what I have:

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{250pt}
\textbf{Chapter 25: Capacitance}\\
$U=\frac{q^2}{2C}=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$ (Electric Potential Energy of a charged capacitor)\\
\end{minipage}}
```

This is the first column of two. I would like the text in paranthesis (Electric potential energy...) to be a column next to the equation, because right now it is wrapping around and starting a new line below the equation which gets very messy.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with more context?

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to go on here, but you can use a `tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|cX|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Chapter 25: Capacitance} & \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  $U = \frac{q^2}{2C} = \frac{1}{2}CV^2$ & (Electric Potential Energy of a charged capacitor) \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

You could let the chapter title span multiple columns, but the appearance may be heavily influenced depending on other content you wish you include in the table.